# Save template for exporting in Odoo 14

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I'm searching how to store an export template via module by doing programming, [I came across this post](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/12-0-export-where-i-can-find-the-saved-export-templates-157731), I searched the same base module (base_export_manager) in 14 but I haven't found it yet.

I understand that could be an XML record that can be saved and installed via a module, so far I just found how to do it [using the Odoo GUI](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/14.0/general/odoo_basics/export-data.html).

Comment: 14.0 version in Migration process. See https://github.com/OCA/server-ux/pull/288. You can do one thing pull this branch and have a try.